# How to import face-recognition with opencv4nodejs object in typescript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, opencv, face-recognition

I'm new to typescript. I tried a lot of ways but i couldn't import face-recognition with opencv4nodejs object using withCv() function.

```js
//works fine in javascript
var cv = require("opencv4nodejs");
var dlib = require("face-recognition").withCv(cv);



//typescript
import * as cv from "opencv4nodejs"
import * as dlib from "face-recognition" //how to use withCv()?

dlib.withCv()  //withCv() does not exist
```

Comment: Add the related type package. Or you have to type it yourself :)

Comment: the typedefinitions are included with it. but index.d.ts contains no definition for withCv function and the additional functions we have when importing using withCv()

https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/face-recognition.js/blob/master/lib/index.d.ts

Comment: Then theyre outdated...